# Symfony FosRestBundle - form route without format

Tags: php, symfony, fosrestbundle

I am trying to bootstrap simple REST app using latest Symfony (2.4.5) with FOSRestBundle (dev-master 6b384c1).

My configuration:

```
fos_rest:
    format_listener: true
    view:
        view_response_listener: true

sensio_framework_extra:
    view:    { annotations: false }
    router:  { annotations: true }
```

My routing:

```
products:
    type:     rest
    resource: Telemetrik\Bundle\ProductBundle\Controller\ProductsController
```

Controller:

```
<?php

// namespace & imports

class ProductsController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * @return Form
     * @View("TelemetrikProductBundle::form.html.twig")
     */
    public function newProductAction()
    {
        return $this->getForm();
    }

    /**
     * @param Request $request
     * @return View|Form
     * @View
     */
    public function postProductsAction(Request $request)
    {
        $form = $this->getForm();

        $form->handleRequest($request);

        if ($form->isValid()) {
            // Logic placeholder
        }

        return $form;
    }

    protected function getForm()
    {
        return $this->createForm(new ProductType());
    }
}
```

When using `router:debug` I get:

```
new_product              GET    ANY    ANY  /products/new.{_format}
post_products            POST   ANY    ANY  /products.{_format}
```

Which is mostly fine BUT since `newProductAction` is supposed to be a form:

- I don't want it to be accessible from formats other than HTML
- I want to access my form from `/products/new` not `/products/new.html` (which right seems to be the only option I can access that resource). If I go to `products/new` I get: `Format '' not supported, handler must be implemented`

Answer (score 2):

```
sensio_framework_extra:
    view:    { annotations: false }
    router:  { annotations: true }

fos_rest:
    routing_loader:
        default_format: json
    format_listener: true
    view:
        view_response_listener: true
```

Answer (score 2):

me helped add format default to json

```
fos_rest:
    routing_loader:
        default_format: json
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your `config.yml`:

```
fos_rest:
    format_listener:
        rules:
            - { path: ^/products/new, priorities: [html, json, xml], fallback_format: html, prefer_extension: false }
```

This should set the html extension as the default for this path, and should make it so the extension is not required.